# Compiling FreeBSD utility from source with debugging symbols

Tags: debugging, gdb, freebsd

I would like to compile the following FreeBSD utility from source: https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/stable/9/sbin/routed/

This repo is however lacking a ./configure file. How can I enable debugging symbols so that I can use gdb to debug this utility?

make file from the repo for reference:

```
# Make `routed` for FreeBSD
# $FreeBSD: stable/9/sbin/routed/Makefile 204405 2010-02-27 10:17:27Z uqs $

PROG=   routed
MAN=    routed.8
SRCS=   if.c input.c main.c output.c parms.c radix.c rdisc.c table.c trace.c
WARNS?= 3
DPADD=  ${LIBMD}
LDADD=  -lmd

SUBDIR= rtquery

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to set `DEBUG_FLAGS=-g` and disable optimization `CFLAGS= -pipe`